# How to add a Label to bottom of ODRefeshControl

Tags: objective-c, xcode, pull-to-refresh

Before when i used Apples UIRefreshControl i could have a label show at the bottom of the Refresh Control like this :

```
UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(addReceipt:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    self.refreshControl = refreshControl;

    NSString *s = @"Swipe Down to Add Receipt";
    NSMutableAttributedString *a = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:s];
    [a addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor darkGrayColor] range:NSRangeFromString(s)];
    refreshControl.attributedTitle = a;
```

Now I switch to ODRefreshControl for the custom activity indicator and i am unable to find a solution! 
My code for ODRefreshControl (Just for it to work):

```
ODRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[ODRefreshControl alloc] initInScrollView:self.tableView];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(dropViewDidBeginRefreshing:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like it is possible to support this type of thing out of the box with this control. Take a look through the code, it doesn't appear to support an `attributedTitle` or anything like it. Also, I'm assuming you're using this control:

https://github.com/Sephiroth87/ODRefreshControl

If that's the case you probably have a few options:

1. You'll have to write some code in the ODRefreshControl source yourself to add the label, most likely in the `initWithScrollView` method, but that might not be totally accurate.
2. Ask the developer to add it in a future release (it appears you already did).
3. Go back to using the Apple Refresh control. Why did you prefer `ODRefreshControl` if you desired a title label?

Comment: 1. That's ok 
2. Yes i already did 
3. I wanted a custom color and activity indicator

Comment: I think those are your only options at this point. Option #4 might be to write your own refresh control.